# sort excel according to lowest CTR and highest impression?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have excel with these columns and rows :

[image]

and this is text :

```
website.com/1   3338    18149   18/39%  3/81
website.com/2   3336    32140   10/38%  6/09
website.com/3   3328    19785   16/82%  4/61
website.com/4   3322    25185   13/19%  5/83
website.com/5   3318    18922   17/54%  4/62
website.com/6   3311    41682   7/94%   6/45
```

Now, I want to sort this excel according to lowest CTR and highest impression

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think to describe my problem clearly, but if you want to tell me what you need to add my question

Comment: The question isn't really clear enough to answer.  1. What is the relationship, if any, between impression and CTR?  Is lowest CTR = highest impression, or are they independent?  If they're independent, how do you want to combine the two value for sorting?  Sort on CTR, then on impression (for continuous data, there isn't likely to be multiple impression values per CTR value, so the 2nd sort term won't change anything)?  Combine the two values with some kind of weighting?  (cont'd)

Comment: 2. CTR contains both a number and a percent.  Besides requiring parsing before you can do anything with it, those two values don't track with each other.  Which value do you want the sort based on?

Comment: It might be a good idea to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1437642/edit) to show us what the expected result in addition to explaining the logic behind it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for :

```
Home > Sort & Filter > Custom sort : .. <define your criteria's>
```

IMHO : I think this is quite a straightforward question, concisely worded.

Anyway.. hope this helps. ( :

Comment: exactly, I want this option